Skipping data while reading file
My task is to write a log parser. A slice of paths is passed as a path and I want to create a slice of the structure of each line. I want to read line by line so as not to take up a lot of memory.
Everything works, but sometimes some data does not have time to be written, therefore, data leakage occurs. How can I fix this?
func test(matches string) (*domain.NGINX, error) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    logChan := make(chan *domain.NGINX)
    errChan := make(chan error)
    
    var logs []*domain.NGINX
    
    go func() {
        for log := range logChan {
            logs = append(logs, log)
        }
    }()
    
    for _, match := range matches {
        wg.Add(1)
    
        go func(filePath string) {
            defer wg.Done()
    
            file, err := os.Open(filePath)
            if err != nil {
                errChan <- fmt.Errorf("accessing path: %v", err)
                return
            }
            defer file.Close()
    
            scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
            for scanner.Scan() {
                line := scanner.Text()
    
                logNGINX, err := ParseLogLineToNGINXObject(line)
                if err != nil {
                    continue
                }
                logChan <- logNGINX
            }
    
            if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
                errChan <- fmt.Errorf("scanning file: %v", err)
                return
            }
        }(match)
    }
    
    
    wg.Wait()
    close(logChan)
    close(errChan)
    
    var err error
    for e := range errChan {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", e)
        err = e
    }
    
    return logs, err

}


You say "does not have time to be written", but you are not writing data anywhere in this example. What do you mean by "data leakage", and what do you need to fix? Start by crating a [mre] demonstrating the problem you are trying to solve.

JFTR, I guess iterating over the file once and checking each line only once for matching against the whole set of matches would actually work faster.

[1/2] I would say, an obvious problem with the presented code is that errChan is unbuffered. Since the channel is closed, and receive operation on it is performed, only after wg.Wait() finishes, any attempt to send to it will block forever. Maybe what I've just described is exactly the problem you've attempted to describe, or maybe not, but this needs to be fixed anyway. To me, a better approach is to make goroutines send back values of a custom struct type with two fields: error and "normal" result. …

[2/2] … When a worker goroutine need to indicate an error, it sends a value with only the field of type error set; when it sends a normal result, that field must be nil. The receiving code must check the error field first when processing the results. Another approach in your case is to make the errChan channel have capacity equal to the number of worker goroutines (of course, if you know it before spawning them): this will make sure all the goroutines will be able to send their errors w/o blocking and exit.

As mentioned in comments, the error write to errChan is blocking, so your goroutine gets stuck there. And because of that, WaitGroup lock isn't released, and your main goroutine is stuck at Wait().
If you want to fail all readings if error occurs, try golang.org/x/sync/errgroup. Or if you want to fail just some, create a []error slice with the same length as matches, and write the error at the index you get from for loop. This isn't racy, as every goroutine access its piece of memory. Later you can use errors.Join for the errors, it filters out the nil values for you.
